# Custom dots slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Есть вот такой пример https://jsfiddle.net/rLLvvpcm/5/ Там вместо обычных dots, идут числа. Как начать исчисление с 1, а не с нуля ?

```
<section class="slider">
   <div>slide1</div>
   <div>slide2</div>
   <div>slide3</div>
   <div>slide4</div>
   <div>slide5</div>
   <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<span class="pagingInfo"></span>

 $(".slider").slick({
 autoplay: true,
 dots: true,
 customPaging : function(slider, i) {
 var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data();
  return '<a>1</a>';
 },
responsive: [{ 
    breakpoint: 500,
    settings: {
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
} 
 }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в этой строчке измените i на i+1: return ''+(i+1)+'';

Comment: супер, спасибо. очень выручили